# Node-Red Get File from SFTP

Tags: sftp, node-red

I am using Node-red to connect to SFTP and to get a file.
Th Problem is that it returns always this error:

> "Error: sftp.realPath: The "string" argument must be of type string or
> an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received type number
> (1645531908336) 1645531908336"

Note: I did not  get this error on "List" and i have tried many SFTP servers. Always the same error

this is the image of my node

[image]

Comment: You really should include the full node name when asking questions or raising issues. As it is there are at least 4 nodes listed on the flows site with sftp in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1645531908336` looks like it is the timestamp from a standard `msg.payload` value from an inject node.

Assuming this is the node-red-contrib-better-sftp node then it looks like it is badly written and will always take the value of `msg.payload` and override any configured path and filename in the node config. This is a really bad design and should only use the input message if the value is left blank in the config.

https://github.com/sublime93/node-red-contrib-better-sftp/blob/10f67d46f3d762b254f7a6f22539ba4c95d6331e/transports/sftp/index.js#L148

So the quick option for you to test is to remove the `msg.payload` from the inject node you are testing with.

You should also raise an issue with the nodes author to fix this behaviour.

EDIT: There already is an open issue (from mid 2020) https://github.com/sublime93/node-red-contrib-better-sftp/issues/9

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I solved it by adding "path/filename" in payload of inject node. And in SFTP Node I checked "Get" Operation and leave "Filename" and "Working directory" Empty!